# ASP MVC 2: how to reset user authorization?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, redirect, authorization

I need to have a global Binary (Linq.Binary) variable (user reference), available for all controllers, which is filled in the process of authorization. I decided to use **TempData**. (May be, there is more suitable way?). I dont need MVC Membership system, only one variable.

When I close website, and then enter it again, my **TempData** is empty, and I need to restart authorization for user again. How to do it?

- **[Authorize]** did not work - user already authorized.
- I tried to insert this code in critical controllers:

> if
>   (!TempData.ContainsKey("CustomerRef"))
>   FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();

but nothing happens.

- I tried to overload **AuthoriseAttribute**, but it looks impossible to look in **TempData** in **AuthoriseAttribute** class.
- I can't store this variable in cookies - it's critical.
- I dont want to store it somewhere in database.

The best way for me is to reset user authorisation some way, if TempData is empty, but I dont know, how to do it. Or, may be I'm re-inventing the wheel? :)

P.S.: I'm using **TempData.Peek()** while getting data, so variable didn't flashes.

Comment: can't you use `Session` variable?

Comment: Thanks, i thought that it wouldn't work, like TempData. I tried and it's working ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to understand your question but it's a little bit vague for me. So you wan't to keep some extra critical user information when they are logged in?

I had a similiar situation , what I did was:

- Create a static class with a `static Dictionary<String,someClassWithExtraValues>`
- During the authentication I would add a new value to the dictionary with as key the `User.Identity.Name`. That way I could always reach the values for the logged in users.
- When the users logs out I delete his value.

You could use it in cookies even if it's critical, once the FormsAuthentication cookie is manually changed it becomes invalid. Ofc there is still cookie stealing etc.

Comment: Thanks! @Eranga helped me with **Session**, and now i'm implementing your model :)

Comment: You should watch out with sessions thou, client sessions can get hijacked/stolen aswell.